# Completely Exact Urls In Express

Tags: node.js, express

How do I use question marks in my express project such as:

```
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html");
});


app.get("/?no-header", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/noheader.html");
});
```

Comment: Query strings are not part of the route `path` that express uses, so in you're example both requests would be handled in one function. The query string values are available in the `request.query` object.

Answer (score 0):

Query strings are removed from the path before comparing to Express routes.  So, both of the above URLs would go to the first request handler.  If you want to separate out those two, you would do that in the same request handler by examining `request.query`:

```
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  if (request.query.hasOwnProperty("no-header")) {
      // ?no-header is present
      response.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/noheader.html");
  } else {
      response.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html");
  }
});
```